# Activating Workbooks written a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on an app that has to use two more excel files for its function. Names of those files change every day so I decided that both of those files are going to be opened from cells that contain functions to change the name based on the date like this.

```
Workbooks.Open Range("C2")
Windows("App.xlsm").Activate
Workbooks.Open Range("C16")
```

Now the problem is that I don't know how to switch between the books that I've opened. Normally I'd use something like this:

```
Windows("A.xlsx").Activate
```

But I clearly can't do that now. My idea was to activate App.xlsm and then activate a workbook written in the cell that I used like his:

```
Windows(Workbooks("App.xlsm").Sheets("Pom").Range("C16").Value).Activate
```

However that doesn't work. Now I'm not sure whether my code is wrong or whether this method just isn't possible. Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use variables to have a handle on the workbooks

```
    Dim wb1 as workbook
    dim wb2 as workbook

    set wb1 = Workbooks.Open (Range("C2"))
    set wb2 = Workbooks.Open (Range("C16"))

    ' Activate wb1 
    wb1.activate
    ' or activate wb2
    wb2.activate
```